# How to release an app to new users and not my existing ones

Tags: react-native, google-play

I have 2 apps, essentially they are the same, but one is a vertical scroll and the other is a horizontal scroll, vertical scroll is a the build which is built on react native and the horizontal one is built on something else.

Now I want to release the vertical scroll one, but only to audience that are not users of my horizontal build.

How do I do that

Any listing changes that can be done on playstore, any third party app,etc

Comment: If you want the current one to co-exist with the new one, you need to create a new application to Google Play.

Answer (score 0):

did you try using firebase a/b testing ?
I think it will help you well with your issue
here is a link to it ![1]: https://firebase.google.com/docs/ab-testing?hl=fr